# using python.itertools to sum slots across multiple lists

Tags: python, arrays, list, dictionary, python-itertools

I have this:

```
[
    [ [1,1,1,0,0,0,0], [0,1,2,3,4,5,6], [1,2,3,4,5,6,7], [2,3,4,5,6,7,8], [3,4,5,6,7,8,9], [4,5,6,7,8,9,0] ]

    , [ [2,2,2,0,0,0,0], [0,1,2,3,4,5,6], [1,2,3,4,5,6,7], [2,3,4,5,6,7,8], [3,4,5,6,7,8,9], [4,5,6,7,8,9,2] ]

    , [ [3,3,3,0,0,0,0], [0,1,2,3,4,5,6], [1,2,3,4,5,6,7], [2,3,4,5,6,7,8], [3,4,5,6,7,8,9], [4,5,6,7,8,9,0] ]
]
```

and I'm trying to get this:

```
[
[[6, 6, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18], [3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21], [6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24], [9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27], [12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27, 2]]
]
```

it's just a sum of all of the relative positions inside the deepest lists.
Right now, I've got 3 nested for-loops and I'm hoping one of you itertools experts can show me a faster & more elegant way to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need itertools for this, you can do this using a list comprehension and `zip(*)`:

```
>>> lst = [[[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]], [[2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 2]], [[3, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]]]
>>> [[sum(y) for y in zip(*x)] for x in zip(*lst)]
[[6, 6, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18], [3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21], [6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24], [9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27], [12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27, 2]]
```

Note that your current expected output is a list that contains a list of lists, which is unnecessary, better keep it to a list of lists.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution without list comprehensions:

```
# In Python 2.x
>>> map(lambda l: map(sum, zip(*l)), zip(*lst))
# In Python 3.x
>>> list(map(lambda l: list(map(sum, zip(*l))), zip(*lst)))
```

Note that this solution is just a proof of concept, you should use the solution by @AshwiniChaudhary as it much more clear and readable.